# Cart sidebar on checkout load dynamic

Tags: checkout, cart, onepage-checkout, shopping-cart

I use a cart in the sidebar of the one page checkout.

This display the products and the total price of the cart.

But I also use some additional cost for payment, so it needs to load dynamically, so that when selecting a payment method that does have additional costs, it updated the cart directly.

Currently the cart is only updated on reload of the entire checkout.

How can I achieve that?

**Code xml:**

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" 
               name="cart_sidebar_checkout" 
               template="checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml" 
               after="checkout-progress-wrapper">
            <action method="addItemRender">
                <type>simple</type>
                <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block>
                <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addItemRender">
                <type>grouped</type>
                <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block>
                <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addItemRender">
                <type>configurable</type>
                <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block>
                <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

**Cart:**

```
<?php
$_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount();
if (empty($_cartQty)) {
    $_cartQty = 0;
}
?>
<div class="block block-progress opc-block-progress minicart-wrapper">
    <div class="block-title-cartsidebar">WINKELMAND</div>
    <?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems() ?>
    <?php $countItems = count($_items); ?>
    <?php if ($countItems): ?>
        <div class="block-items-cartsidebar">
            <ul id="cart-sidebar" class="mini-products-list awesome">
                <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <li class="subtotal-side-verzenden">
                    <span class="label-verzendkosten">Verzendkosten</span>
                    <span class="label-verzenkosten-price">Gratis</span>
                </li>
                <?php $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote() ?>
                <?php if ($cart->getFoomanSurchargeAmount() > 0) : ?>
                    <li class="subtotal-side-paymentcost">
                        <span
                            class="label-surcharge-description"><?php echo $cart->getFoomanSurchargeDescription() ?></span>
                        <span
                            class="label-verzenkosten-price"><?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($cart->getFoomanSurchargeAmount()) ?></span>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <li class="subtotal-side">
                        <span class="label">
                        <?php echo $this->__('Totaal') ?><?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()) ?>
                            <?php if ($_subtotalInclTax = $this->getSubtotalInclTax()): ?>
                                <br/>(<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_subtotalInclTax) ?><?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getIncExcText(true) ?>)
                            <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="block-wijzig-cartsidebar">
            <a class="cart-link-head" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart'); ?>">
                <?php echo $this->__('Wijzig uw winkelmand'); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php if ($_cartQty && $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()): ?>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="empty"><?php echo $this->__('You have no items in your shopping cart.') ?></p>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please show your code.

Comment: @AmitBera Edit my question

Answer (score 1):

If you make  cart siderbar block as

**child block of magento default processbar** which is  in rwd theme then it is be automatically update as each step of checkout Onepage.

So, you need to change the reference name right (`<reference name="right">`)  to  checkout.progress `<reference name="checkout.progress">`

**Code:**

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="checkout.progress"> <!--change the right to checkout.progress -->
        .....
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

And add  `echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar_checkout')` 
code at `checkout/onepage/progress.phtml`.

If process bar is working but cartsidebar is **not render** then you need to add xml code at `checkout.xml` as on **right reference** of `checkout_onepage_index` handler, Magento was doing unset all **child blocks** using:

```
 <action method="unsetChildren"></action>
```

And also call this checkout sidber at `checkout_onepage_progress` handler.

```
<checkout_onepage_progress>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar_checkout" template="checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml" >
            <action method="addItemRender">
                <type>simple</type>
                <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block>
                <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addItemRender">
                <type>grouped</type>
                <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block>
                <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="addItemRender">
                <type>configurable</type>
                <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block>
                <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_progress>
```

Comment: Thanks! Edit the code as you described. Process bar is working and cart is displayed in the process bar. But the cart is not updating on each step. It is still only updating on refresh. I also set action method to unsetChilderen.

Comment: answer update.. no need to add <action method="unsetChildren"></action>

Comment: I removed the action method unsetChilderen, but it still does not update.

Comment: Inside the rwd theme I also do not see any <reference name="checkout.progress"> in the checkout.xml file

Comment: let me check...

Comment: update please check..

Comment: Thanks, tried that new code, but that also does not work. What should I do with the unsetChilderen part? Should I call or remove something?

Comment: Did you found a solution to this Amit?

Comment: i did not check..

Comment: Hi Amit, did you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: i will checking on today